# Splitting using select for 2 or more semicolon delimited items

Tags: xslt

Input

```
         <row>
          <name-prf>Prokofiev, Serge (piano); Adolph Bolm (dancer)</name-prf>
            </row>
```

Desired Output

```
<subject>
        <name type="personal">
           <namePart>Prokofiev, Serge (piano)</namePart>
           <role>
              <roleTerm type="code" authority="marcrelator">prf</roleTerm>
           </role>
        </name>
     </subject>

 <subject>
    <name type="personal">
       <namePart>Adolph Bolm (dancer)</namePart>
       <role>
          <roleTerm type="code" authority="marcrelator">prf</roleTerm>
       </role>
    </name>
 </subject>
```

Current code

```
        <subject>
            <name type="personal">
                <namePart>
                 <xsl:value-of select="name-prf"/>
                </namePart>
                <role>
                    <roleTerm type="code" authority="marcrelator">prf</roleTerm>
                </role>
            </name>
        </subject>
```

I've been largely using value of rather than individual templates because the order is very different from the initial sheet, but I do feel like the solution here is probably forcing a template call multiple times?

Comment: Do a search for *tokenize*. It's a function in XSLT 2.0 - in XSLT 1.0 you need a recursive named template, or a processor that supports it as an extension function.

Comment: I'm just not quite sure how to use tokenize in this context. I can use 2.0

Comment: for example this doesn't work: <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/*/name-prf/tokenize(.,'; '))">
                <person><xsl:value-of select="."/></person>
            </xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just not quite sure how to use tokenize in this context. I can use
>   2.0

Something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(name-prf, '; ')">
        <subject>
            <name type="personal">
                <namePart>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </namePart>
                <role>
                    <roleTerm type="code" authority="marcrelator">prf</roleTerm>
                </role>
            </name>
        </subject>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ah, if I'd checked back again I would have seen this. I think this works as well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to XSLT 1.0 add this as an extension function:

```
public XPathNodeIterator Tokenize(string value, string separators)
{
  XElement root = new XElement("Root");
  string[] tokens = value.Split(separators.ToCharArray());

  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
  {
    root.Add(tokens[i]);
  }

  return root.CreateNavigator().Select("/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tokenize was the key, I wasn't able to straight tokenize but I could tokenize with a parameter, not sure why that made a difference:

```
 <xsl:param name="seperator" select="'; '"/>

 <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(name-prf/tokenize(.,$seperator))">
                <person><xsl:value-of select="."/></person>
            </xsl:for-each>
```